# I am getting NullPointerException from service method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using **JPA** in **spring MVC** with **MySQL** database.
In my *persistence-beans.xml* as follows

```
    `

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

        <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.repository" />
        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <jpa:repositories
            base-package="com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.repository" />

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="dirverClassName"
                value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nitindb" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="nitin8855" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"
                ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            <property name="packageToScan"
                value="com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.entity" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

`

and my service-beans.xml as follows`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="productService"  class="com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.service.ProductServiceImpl">
        <property name="productService"  ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

`

and *applicationContext.xml* `

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <import resource="service-beans.xml"/>
   <import  resource="persistence-beans.xml"/>

</beans>
```

`

and this my service implementation class `

```
package com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.Service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.entity.Product;
import com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.repository.ProductRepository;

@Service("productService")
@Transactional
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private EntityManager entityManager ;

    private ProductRepository producrRepository;

    public void setProducrRepository(ProductRepository producrRepository) {
        this.producrRepository = producrRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
        return producrRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(int id) {

        return producrRepository.getOne(id);
    }

}
```

`

and my controller `

```
package com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.contoller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.Service.ProductServiceImpl;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    private ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl;


    public void setProductServiceImpl(ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl) {
        this.productServiceImpl = productServiceImpl;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homeController(ModelMap map) {
        String msg = "My name is nitin";
        map.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        System.out.println(productServiceImpl.getAllProduct());
        return "home";
    }

}
```

`

I think I am unable to connect the database through **JPA**. It returns null data. My credentials absolutely right so Whenever I use **JdbcTemplate** I got return valid data from the database.
My controller also working, whenever I call the service method it gives me NullPointerException, that means database not connected and gives this exception. 
stack trace as follows `

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp.contoller.MainController.homeController(MainController.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`

Please tell me how to connect the database through **JPA**

Answer (score 3):

The error says that `productServiceImpl` is `null`. You should `@Autowired` on top of it like this:

```
@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl;
```

Or you can make a constructor for that class which is recommended:

```
@Autowired
public MainController(ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl){
    this.productServiceImpl = productServiceImpl;
}
```

Also you should change `persistence-beans.xml` to this:

```
<context:component-scan
            base-package="com.nit.SpringMVC_WebApp" />
```

To scan controller annotation.

Comment: +1, use constructor injection to prevent nullable and circular dependencies. Be sure to add @Autowired above the constructor to make this work.

Comment: @ErikSchouten tnx I added it to constructor.

Comment: I tried with @Autowierd but I am getting the same exception i.e. NullPointerException with HTTP Status 500.

Comment: @nitinsonwane you really should use Spring Boot, it does all this configuration automatically, no config files needed

Comment: Thanx, I will move to spring boot. But in this XML as my opinion, I couldn't make a proper connection to the database that's the reason I am getting null exception whenever I call service method in the controller.  I used all the above suggestions and I got the same exception.

Comment: @nitinsonwane U are using xml and annotation at the same time which makes you troubles. as Erik suggested try using Spring Boot, It will configure automatically for you. You have other problems in your code as I see. You also need to autowired `ProductRepository`. Just try to migrate to Spring boot to solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

You need an `@Autowired` on `productServiceImpl` in `MainController`. Or set the field via constructor injection. The later is the recommended approach.

Comment: I used `@Autowired` on `productServiceImpl` and I am getting the same exception i.e. NullPointerException